# How to count multiple properties values in array of objects using lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is it posible to count both `name` and `city` using one variable without using `_.merge`?

```
const people = [
  { 'name': 'Adam', 'city': 'London', 'age': 34  },
  { 'name': 'Adam',  'age': 34  },
    { 'name': 'John', 'city': 'London','age': 23   },
    { 'name': 'Bob', 'city': 'Paris','age': 69   },
   { 'name': 'Mark', 'city': 'Berlin','age': 69   },

]
const names = _.countBy(people, (person) => person.name);
const cities = _.countBy(people, (person) => person.city);

console.log(_.merge(names,cities)); // Object {Adam: 2, Berlin: 1, Bob: 1, John: 1, London: 2, Mark: 1, Paris: 1, undefined: 1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Lodash, simply use [`Array#Reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
const people = [
  { 'name': 'Adam', 'city': 'London', 'age': 34 },
  { 'name': 'Adam',  'age': 34 },
  { 'name': 'John', 'city': 'London','age': 23 },
  { 'name': 'Bob', 'city': 'Paris','age': 69 },
  { 'name': 'Mark', 'city': 'Berlin','age': 69 },
]

const result = people.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.name] = acc[curr.name] ? acc[curr.name] + 1 : 1;
  acc[curr.city] = acc[curr.city] ? acc[curr.city] + 1 : 1;
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```